# Need help my object isn't showing

Tags: modeling, objects

could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Your object is in fact showing. You can see the edges connecting vertices (which are not displayed in object mode). If you want a face/polygon then you will have to create one.

Comment: thank you, now is showing

Comment: Great that you found a solution. I encourage you to add an answer detailing the steps to solve the problem. That way others can profit from the solution as well.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Please copy paste your answer in the answer box below. That way, others can upvote it and you can mark it as the correct solution. =)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Press L to select the whole object, then go to edit mode, pressing TAB, and click the hotkey F. To add a face in the object.